# Excluding retweets from search query

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to build a simple twitter reader for specific hashtags and only for tweets containing images.

I want to exclude retweets and have been trying various ways to do it. I can of course take out retweets post having queried them but they count against the number of tweets I can get.

I was reading about a trick where you could add -RT to your search query but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=#reviews&filter=images';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);


$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(), true);

foreach($string['statuses'] as $item)
{

    echo '<p>Time and Date of Tweet: '.$item['created_at'].'</p>';
    echo '<p class="tweet">'. $item['text'].'</p>';

    echo '<img class="author" src="'. $item['user']['profile_image_url_https'] .'"><br />';
    echo '<p class="author-txt">Tweeted by: '. $item['user']['name'].'</p>';

    foreach ($item['entities']['media'] as $media) { 
        echo '<img src="'. $media['media_url'] .'">';
        echo '<div class="clr"></div>';
    } 
  }

?>
```

More specifically the search query I am trying to add the ' -RT' to is this

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=#bookreviews&filter=images';
```

I tried adding it to the end like this

```
$getfield = '?q=#reviews&filter=images -RT';
```

But still no luck.

The result page is here

http://000fff.org/readersanomynous/

Comment: What happens if you try `?q=#reviews%20-RT&filter=images`

Comment: I get a: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/thompete/000fff.org/readersanomynous/index.php on line 60